# Summing columns using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am searching for a more elegant way of summing 2 columns, month to date using LINQ. I have the following query which works just fine but it looks inefficient.

What's a better way of rewriting it?

Thank you

```
TotalLaborHours = db.Timesheet.Where(a => a.Date <= MDate & a.Date.Month == MDate.Month)
                              .Select(a => a.RegularPaidHours).Sum() + 
                  db.Timesheet.Where(a => a.Date <= MDate & a.Date.Month == MDate.Month)
                              .Select(a => a.OvertimeHours).Sum();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this not have the same effect?

```
TotalLaborHours = db.Timesheet
    .Where(a => a.Date <= MDate & a.Date.Month == MDate.Month)
    .Select(a => a.RegularPaidHours + a.OvertimeHours).Sum();
```

Comment: Or just TotalLaborHours = db.Timesheet         .Sum(a => a.Date <= MDate && a.Date.Month == MDate.Month?       a.RegularPaidHours + a.OvertimeHours : 0);

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an anonymous type which is the sum of the two columns, then sum the sum like so:

```
TotalLaborHours = db.Timesheet
    .Where(a => a.Date <= MDate & a.Date.Month == MDate.Month)
    .Select(a => new { hrs = a.RegularPaidHours + a.OvertimeHours }).Sum(b => b.hrs);
```

Comment: As it's currently written, doesn't compiles. You need to change your `Sum` method to this `Sum(c => c.hrs)` to make this compiles.